# How to rename multiple files using a batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

I am trying to rename all the xml files within a directory. I have tried the following:

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set a=1
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('/PolicyDL/*.xml') do (
  set "name=%%F"
  ren "!name!" "!a!.xml"
set /a a+=1
)
```

However, I receive the following error:

```
The System Cannot find the Path Specified.
```

PolicyDL is a directory in the same place as the script.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues:

- the Windows path separator is `\`, the `/` usually indicates command options;
- I assume that the directory `PolicyDL` is a sub-directory of the current one; if you want to point to the directory where the batch file resides, replace the prefix `.\` by `%~dp0` in the code below;
- `for /F` tries to execute the part in between `''` as a command; I suggest to use `dir /B /A:-D` here; (instead you could use a normal `for` loop without `/F`, but in this particular case, some files might be attempted to be renamed twice as `for` does not enumerate the whole set of matching files before starting to process them...)
- the sort order of the returned files depends on the file system (unless you do some sorting by `dir`, like `/O:N` to sort by name, or `/O:D` to sort by age, for instance);
- having delayed expansion enabled during reading a `for` meta-variable like `%%i` causes problems with exclamation marks; toggle delayed expansion so that it is enabled only when it is really needed;

Here is my coding suggestion:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set /A "a=1"
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /B /A:-D /O:N ".\PolicyDL\*.xml"') do (
    set "name=%%F"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    ren "!name!" "!a!.xml"
    endlocal
    set /A "a+=1"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set a=1
for %%F in ("PolicyDL\*.xml") do (
  set "name=%%F"
  ren "!name!" "!a!.xml"
  set /a a+=1
)
```

I think it just wants `\` not `/` and I changed it to double quotes to wrap the path/file.